# How to get the daily usage of android phone and apps?

Tags: android

I want to know how much time the user using the android phone.  The phone may be booted multiple times in a day, so the `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` may not handle the case.

Is there a way to read the system log to know the timestamp system boot up and the timestamp system shutdown?  Or I need `BroadcastReceiver` to catch `BOOT_COMPLETE` and `SHUT_DOWN` event and write into storage?

Comment: Integrating Google firebase (https://firebase.google.com/) might be an option. It would give individual usage times but assuming you are just wanting some insight into how often your app is used it does provide an average session time (among other things such as crash analytics etc)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you make an app with a BroadcastReceiver which triggers at `BOOT_COMPLETE` and starts a service, inside which you get the system time (Let's say X). Another BroadcastReceiver will get triggered by `SHOT_DOWN` and sends the message (via Binder or other method) to the running service which again gets the system time (Let's say Y) and saves the difference between them in SharedPreferences (Y-X).

This way you can easily know how much time (up to nanoseconds) the device was on.

Note that you are not doing any long-running process inside the BroadcastReceiver, but start a service from it instead. Service processes have higher priority and will not get killed by the Android OS. Also, I've read that BroadcastReceivers have some time limitations (about 10 seconds) before they get destroyed by the system.

Comment: Thank you.  So the BroadcastReceiver is a short-life process triggered by event, we need inter-process communication to share data with activity and service?

Comment: Not necessarily inter-process. Your BroadcastReceivers and Services (of the same app) will run in the same process. You just have to set the communication pattern. You need a service because a receiver is not designed to run a long time.